# Installing Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 16.04 running MeteorJS app

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, meteor, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a MeteorJS app running on my Digital Ocean server (using nginx). I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install Let's Encrypt certificate on my domain, but it failed on this command:

`sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d   luludeals.com -d www.luludeals.com`

I get this error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. www.luludeals.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks suffic
ient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.luludeals.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/AFx6B3zOXAm1aR0ZxyW
kOuBvlesQZRAa3ut551_u3Ms: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/462460ddb68331f2c370d7afc3d", luludeals.com
(http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http:/
/luludeals.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/qFLoXVN5sZaZGZvwI-uSlTQx4BXL7vXQpYmv5I72KP0: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/462460ddb68331f2c370d7afc3d"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.luludeals.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from http://www.luludeals.com/.well-known
   /acme-challenge/AFx6B3zOXAm1aR0ZxyWkOuBvlesQZRAa3ut551_u3Ms:
   "<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__"
   href="/462460ddb68331f2c370d7afc3d"

   Domain: luludeals.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from http://luludeals.com/.well-known
   /acme-challenge/qFLoXVN5sZaZGZvwI-uSlTQx4BXL7vXQpYmv5I72KP0:
   "<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__"
   href="/462460ddb68331f2c370d7afc3d"
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file looks like that:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/luludeals;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        }


        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            #
        # location ~ \.php$ {
        # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        # }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        # location ~ /\.ht {
        # deny all;
        #}
   }
```

Do you know how to solve this problem?
To install MeteorJS I used [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/xenial/install_passenger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your webroot-path is `/var/www/luludeals` not `/var/www/html`